# gulp css:watch exited with code null

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I installed this library:

```
npm install --save-dev css-loader
```

https://github.com/webpack-contrib/css-loader

now, when I want to run  my project I got this errors:

> yarn start

```
yarn run v1.5.1
$ cross-env NODE_PATH=./app concurrently --kill-others "node app/server" "gulp css:watch"
[1] [10:00:19] 
[1] Using gulpfile ~/Desktop/react js/shadyab/gulpfile.js
[1] [10:00:19] Starting 'css'...
[1] [10:00:19] 
[1] Finished 'css' after 320 ms
[1] [10:00:19] Starting 'css:watch'...
[1] [10:00:19] 
[1] Finished 'css:watch' after 9.38 ms
[0] Server is listening to port: 3000
[0] events.js:183
[0]       throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
[0]       ^
[0] 
[0] Error: listen EADDRINUSE :::3000
[0]     at Object._errnoException (util.js:1022:11)
[0]     at _exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1044:20)
[0]     at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (net.js:1367:14)
[0]     at listenInCluster (net.js:1408:12)
[0]     at Server.listen (net.js:1492:7)
[0]     at Function.listen (/Users/sm_emamian/Desktop/react js/shadyab/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:618:24)
[0]     at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/sm_emamian/Desktop/react js/shadyab/app/server/server.js:73:8)
[0]     at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
[0]     at loader (/Users/sm_emamian/Desktop/react js/shadyab/node_modules/babel-register/lib/node.js:144:5)
[0]     at Object.require.extensions.(anonymous function) [as .js] (/Users/sm_emamian/Desktop/react js/shadyab/node_modules/babel-register/lib/node.js:154:7)
[0] node app/server exited with code 1
--> Sending SIGTERM to other processes..
[1] gulp css:watch exited with code null
error An unexpected error occurred: "Command failed.
Exit code: 1
Command: sh
Arguments: -c cross-env NODE_PATH=./app concurrently --kill-others \"node app/server\" \"gulp css:watch\"
Directory: /Users/sm_emamian/Desktop/react js/shadyab
Output:
".
info If you think this is a bug, please open a bug report with the information provided in "/Users/sm_emamian/Desktop/react js/shadyab/yarn-error.log".
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

Comment: Seems like you already have something else running on port 3000.

Comment: yes. I killed all terminals and my problem solved. :-? I think the error is misleading.